# How to access objects outside of a lambda inside forEach?

Tags: java, lambda

I have the following code:

```
String fields = "";
listofObjects.stream().forEach(l -> fields = fields + l.text);
```

Which doesn't work, because `fields` should be final. How can I modify `fields` using lambdas?

Comment: you can do `listofObjects.forEach` no need to `.stream()`

Comment: always remember that stream lambdas might be executed in parallel - and that's the reason why Java protects you from accidentially overwriting non final attributes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Streams and lambdas should generally be stateless. Here's the conventional solution for your case:

```
String fields = listofObjects.stream()
        .map(l -> l.text)
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Answer (score 8):

The smallest change to make that work would just be to use a `StringBuilder` instead - and that would be more efficient:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
listofObjects.stream().forEach(l -> builder.append(l.text));
String fields = builder.toString();
```

As Martin notes, `Collectors.joining()` provides general string joining capabilities, but you need to map your stream of objects to a stream of strings first. (Easy to do with `map`, and if you need to do this very often you could always create your own collector to do that.)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do exactly the same:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
listofObjects.stream().forEach(l -> builder.append(l.text));
```

But a more functional approach would be

```
fields = listofObjects.stream().map(l -> l.text).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use [reduce](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html):

```
String fields = listofObjects.stream()
                             .reduce((x, y) -> x + y).orElse("");
```

Or, per @shmosel's comment below:

```
String fields = listofObjects.stream()
                             .reduce("", String::concat);
```

Comment: Or `.reduce("", String::concat);`. But why would you use `reduce()` when there's a more efficient collector just for this?

Comment: @shmosel true, reduce has another overloaded version that takes an initial value which can be used. I don't see any added value of doing one over another and also not over the solution you provided. Do you see a pro/con to one of them ?

Comment: The value of the overload I suggested is that it doesn't require the `get()` call, which should generally be avoided. If you're going with the `Optional` overload, at least use `orElse("")` to reflect OP's intent. The value of the collector is that it's arguably more idiomatic and therefore more familiar. Plus it uses a `StringJoiner` internally, which avoids the cost of repeated concatenation.